# Adding padding to customised text

Tags: html, css

jsfiddle.net/6210d8fs/

Hello,

I can't figure out how to add padding to the 'view more' text - I want it below all the rest of the text. can somebody help? then span style works if i want to change the color, but not when adding padding

Comment: not really sure what you're trying top achieve... this? http://jsfiddle.net/ybm0847y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`padding-top` or `padding-bottom` doesn't work for inline elements, you should make it `inline-block` or `block`: http://jsfiddle.net/zcab1u7h/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:
http://jsfiddle.net/6210d8fs/3/

What I did was *set the style of the view more element individually*, as well as change the `p` style to block. What you had done is set the style of all the `p` elements to have `padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;` and `margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;`. Using the cascading nature of CSS (Hence the name, *cascading* style sheets), I simply set the ID of the **view more** element to `viewMore`, and styled it after the `p` styling.